# How to fix inconsistency of mesh into the "body" in 2.80?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edit-mode

I am relatively new to Blender 2.80. I am making a hair mesh when I see this:
[image]

You can see **the yellow arrows** pointing to the "**outstanding**" faces, which just looks weird for a hair. *Hair needs to be smooth!*

1. In Blender, I tried selecting these faces and their adjoining faces,
   hitting "F". The result is still "outstanding".
2. I also tried "merge-to center" but...still looking even more absurd.

What is **the proper way** to cope with *the naughty faces*?

Here is the project file:[image]

Comment: Go to edit mode, select all, then `mesh > normals > recalculate outside`.

Comment: Hi, Christopher. I've tried your suggestion, but the result looks the same as above and looks like it creates more outstanding faces : (

Comment: Hmmm. It's hard to tell what's going on without seeing your project. Could you upload your .blend file? You can do it here - https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Also, you could try select all then  `mesh > cleanup > merge by distance`.

Comment: I have tried the "cleanup" but not getting any better. Here is the project file:[<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=864dwASP" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/864dwASP/) Thx, man!

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you have misplaced sharp edges, although I think it was also made worse by duplicate vertices. The first thing I did was merge by distance, which removed 1000+ vertices, then I started selecting the sharpened edges that didn't seem to flow with the rest. I then cleared the sharpened edges. See below:  [image: SharpEdges]

The result is a much smoother look, with the offending faces "gone". I only did this on a handful of edges to test - there are quite a few of these places where you might want to unsharpen the edges, but probably also some others where you want to add some sharpness. You will have to look over your model and decide for yourself.

[image: SmoothEdges]

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much. I got to figure it out on my own since this is the first time I know about "sharp" edges"...hahahaha, thank you so much for help!

Comment: I have tried this with Ctrl + E and see the "clear sharp" option. It worked! Thanks man!